# Add attributes to Angular 2 Component Selector

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to add attributes to the custom selector I create in the angular 2 component implementation.

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-node',     // add attributes to this selector 
template: `<div> <ng-content></ng-content> </div>`    
})
```

So that when I do `<my-node>` The dom generates the selector with these extra attributes

`<my-node flex="25" layout="row">`

I don't want to hard code these attributes every time I do `<my-node>`. I want those attributes to be part of the selectors constructed template.

Something like this is what Im looking for but not seeing anything like it in the api

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-node',     
selectorAttributes: `layout="row"`  // generates <my-node layout="row">
template: `<div> <ng-content></ng-content> </div>`    
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not put them on the root element of the template?

Comment: Have you tried @HostBinding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `host` of `@Component` metadata property.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-node',     // add attributes to this selector 
   template: `<div> <ng-content></ng-content> </div>`,
   host: { // this is applied to 'my-node' in this case
      "[class.some-class]": "classProperty", 
      "[attr.some-attr]": "attrProperty", 
   },   
})
```

Here is an example [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/y3WWbzQZGhwyqnekKBvq?p=preview) . See `app/app.component.ts`

Comment: Adding host: '[attr]="componentProp"'  errors, can you link to docs with this "host:" implementation please?

Comment: Pretty sure this is what I need but still get errors. `Can't bind to 'attr' since it isn't a known property of 'my-node'.`

Comment: `If 'my-node' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

Comment: Tried adding `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],` but it still errors

Comment: "[attr]": ''prop" would work if `attr` is a native property like `disabled`. In other cases use "[attr.yourAttr]": ''prop"

Comment: I must be missing something because the <my-node> element is not getting any attributes added

Comment: I added an example plunk to the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: ManyThanks!! I was missing the property definition in the exported class.

Comment: This applies the attributes, but it doesn't seem to invoke any directives/components selected by those attribute names. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: i am using Angular 5.2.11, and this is the new behaviour: "attr": ''prop" would work if attr is a native property like disabled. In other cases use "[attr.yourAttr]": ''prop". (so for native properties like id, tabindex etc.  without square bracket)

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use the HostBinding dectorator

```
@HostBinding('attr.layout')
layout = 'row';
```

Comment: This one worked great for me. I think it is the best solution because you can put it next to the other class variables like inputs, outputs, private / public component info, etc. It also allows you to predictably set values and get Typescript to analyze your code if you want to evaluate a function as your HostBinding value.